# Suggestions on how to test a BufferedReader and FileReader that takes in strings and puts them into an ArrayList

Tags: java, file-io, mocking, tdd, mockito

I have a class which has a method that reads a text file line by line and then puts each line into an `ArrayList` of Strings. Here is my code:

```
public class ReadFile {

    public List<String> showListOfCourses() throws IOException {
        String filename = "countriesInEurope.txt";
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(filename);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        List<String> courseList = new ArrayList<>();

        while (true) {
            String line = br.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                break;
            }

            courseList.add(line);
        }
        br.close();

        return courseList;
    }

}
```

I was hoping for a few suggestions on how to test this method through `Mockito` involving Arrange/Act/Assert. I have heard readers which involve text files can be tricky to test and that creating a temporary file for is not best practice as it uses up memory? Any suggestions will be really appreciated.

Comment: I would create a temporary file containing two or three lines of text. I don't see why this would not be "best practice" or "use up memory". Of course, if the class allowed the data source to be set from outside (ie, a given `Reader` object) it would not require an actual file. Mocking the Java IO API is certainly *not* a good practice.

Comment: Just a reminder: if you're practicing TDD, you write the test first so you're not looking at code wondering how to test it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the filename `countriesInEurope.txt` is hardcoded in your implementation, this is not testable.
A good way to make this testable would be to refactor the method to take a `Reader` as parameter:

```
public List<String> showListOfCourses(Reader reader) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
    List<String> courseList = new ArrayList<>();

    // ...

    return courseList;
}
```

Your main implementation could pass a `FileReader` to this. On the other hand when testing, your test method could pass a `StringReader` instance, which is easy to create with a sample content as a simple string, no temporary files needed, for example:

```
@Test
public void showListOfCourses_should_read_apple_orange_banana() {
    Reader reader = new StringReader("apple\norange\nbanana");
    assertEquals(Arrays.asList("apple", "orange", "banana"), showListOfCourses(reader));
}
```

Btw the name of the method is not good,
as it doesn't "show" anything.
`readListOfCourses` would make more sense.

Comment: The reader is a *dependency* of this class. One of the basic rules of OOP is **single responsibility**.  In that sense  *object creation for dependencies* is **not** a responsibility of this class. In fact the only classes that create objects (other than DTOs or Wrappers like `BufferedReader`) should be factories or alike which initially construct the programs object tree. Sticking to that approach will almost always give you good testable classes with the exception of the Factories and the initializer classes.

Answer (score 2):

The problematic lines for tests are

```
String filename = "countriesInEurope.txt";
FileReader fr = new FileReader(filename);
```

because

1. the filename is hard coded and can not be replaced for tests
2. The `FileReader` uses the underlying system io which is hard to mock

Nervertheless there are ways to make your code testable

**1. Introduce a constructor to parametrize the `ReadFile` object creation**

```
public class ReadFile {

    private String filename;

    public ReadFile(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public List<String> showListOfCourses() throws IOException {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(filename);

        ...

        return courseList;
    }

}
```

In your test you can then create a `ReadFile` object that uses some test file.
With this strategy you can achieve 100% line coverage, but your test must access a real file on the file system. So you can't write it as a pure unit test.

**2. Extract the problematic lines to an overridable method**

```
public class ReadFile {

    public List<String> showListOfCourses() throws IOException {
        Reader courcesReader = openCoursesFile();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(courcesReader);
        List<String> courseList = new ArrayList<>();

        // ...

        return courseList;
    }

    protected Reader openCoursesFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
       return new FileReader("countriesInEurope.txt");
    }

}
```

In your test you can then subclass the `ReadFile` class and override the `Reader openCoursesFile()` method. E.g.

```
@Test
public void showCources() throws IOException {

    ReadFile readFile = new ReadFile() {
        protected Reader openCoursesFile() throws java.io.FileNotFoundException {
            return new StringReader("Germany\nItaly\nFrance");
        };
    };

    List<String> showListOfCourses = readFile.showListOfCourses();

    Assert.assertEquals(Arrays.asList("Germany", "Italy", "France"), showListOfCourses);
}
```

With this strategy you can write your test as a pure unit test, because you substitute the file access with a `StringReader` (only in memory). The only line you can't test is

```
return new FileReader("countriesInEurope.txt");
```

So no 100% line coverage.

**EDIT**

**3. Introduce a constructor and pass it a `Reader` object creation**

```
public class ShowListOfCoursesReader {

    private Reader reader;

    public ReadFile(Reader reader) {
        this.reader = reader;
    }

    public List<String> read() throws IOException {
        // read with reader and transform each line to the
        // output object.
        // In your case just the line you read, but it could
        // also be a date or a address object
        ...

        return courseList;
    }

}
```

In your test you can then create a `ShowListOfCoursesReader` object that uses the passed reader. A reader can also be a [`StringReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html).
With this strategy you can achieve 100% line coverage and pure unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

Extract dependencies so that they can be mocked/stubbed and injected when testing. It also helps narrow down the scope of the class to its core responsibilities.

```
public class CourseReader {
    private BufferedReader reader;

    public CourseReader(BufferedReader br) {
        this.reader = br;
    }

    public List<String> GetListOfCourses() throws IOException {
        List<String> courseList = new ArrayList<>();
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {   
            courseList.add(line);
        }
        return courseList;
    }    
}
```

Now to test this class the dependencies can be arranged before hand.

```
@Test
public void GetListOfCourses_should_read_3_Courses() {
    //Arrange
    List<String> expected = Arrays.asList("course1", "course2", "course3");

    Reader reader = new StringReader("course1\ncourse2\ncourse3");

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);

    CourseReader sut = new CourseReader(bufferedReader);

    //Act
    List<String> actual = sut.GetListOfCourses();

    //Assert
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

This can be refactored even further to abstract away the implementation details.

```
public interface IReaderWrapper {
    String readLine();
    void close();
}
```

and use that as the dependency

```
public class CourseReader {
    private IReaderWrapper reader;

    public CourseReader(IReaderWrapper reader) {
        this.reader = reader;
    }

    public List<String> GetListOfCourses() throws IOException {
        List<String> courseList = new ArrayList<>();
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {   
            courseList.add(line);
        }
        reader.close();
        return courseList;
    }    
}
```

That way only the interface needs to be mocked when testing. The implementations of the interface will worry about how the data is actually read.

```
@Test
public void GetListOfCourses_should_read_3_Courses() {
    //Arrange
    List<String> expected = Arrays.asList("course1", "course2", "course3");

    IReaderWrapper mockedReader = mock(IReaderWrapper.class);

    when(mockedReader.readLine())
        .thenReturn(expected[0], expected[1], expected[2], null);

    CourseReader sut = new CourseReader(mockedReader);

    //Act
    List<String> actual = sut.GetListOfCourses();

    //Assert
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
    //verify that the close method was called.
    verify(mockedReader).close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems like you try to test framework, in this particular case JDK. I would consider more convenient API:

```
Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("blablabla.txt"));
```

or

```
Files.lines(Paths.get("blablabla.txt"));
```

and cover by tests higher layer of abstraction - a place where list of strings is used.